# Rails validate all attributes in object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is there a way to validate the true presence of all attributes in a given model object? Or do I have to list each attribute with `presence: true`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an array of all your model attributes, you can use `YourModel.attribute_names`. However you cannot really validate the presence of all your attributes (such as the `id`, `created_at`) since these will be blank during validation when creating a record.

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  NON_VALIDATABLE_ATTRS = ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"] #or any other attribute that does not need validation
  VALIDATABLE_ATTRS = YourModel.attribute_names.reject{|attr| NON_VALIDATABLE_ATTRS.include?(attr)}

  validates_presence_of VALIDATABLE_ATTRS
end
```

Comment: Amazing thanks, just saved me typing 40 attributes. It's validate**s**_presence_of btw, if you want to edit it?

Comment: `validates_presence_of` is a deprecated syntax. It's better to use `validates :list, :of, :attribute, :names, presence: true` instead.

Comment: Also, instead of maintaining two constants, you could simply get the array of validatable fields by doing an array difference: `YourModel.attribute_names - %w(id created_at modified_at)`.

Comment: @Andrei Horak `validates_presence_of` is not deprecated. There is no mention of deprecation in [Rails 4.2.5](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)

Comment: @AbM actually it was in Rails 3, when the validations have been moved to `ActiveModel` and `validates` was introduced. The syntax may still be used, but the `validates` syntax is the preferred one. See also the note on 'Sexy validations': http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#patches-and-deprecations

Comment: Late but still relevant. This answer is not a good practice because it requires you to have the db created by the time you load the classes. In cases like CircleCI this code will fail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can add all the attributes in a single line like this :

```
validates :name, :login, :email, presence: true
```

Comment: Any other way of just doing them all? I've got `validates :orders,:diagnosis,:posterior_flattening,
  :circumference,:ap,:ml,:frontal_area,:parietal_lateral,
  :ear_position,:scan_file,:transfer_name,:modifications,
  :primary_mods,:top_opening,:side_opening,:chape_position, presence: true`. It's tiresome typing them all.

Comment: Thinking more about this is not elegant, eventually you can use attributes array as suggested above. Personally I stick with this since it's straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all attribute names in an `Array` with the method `.attributes_names`.

Then everything you have to do is to add this `array` to the `validates_presence_of` method.

**Example:**

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of attribute_names.reject { |attr| attr =~ /id|created_at|updated_at/i }
end
```